# What GUI file explorers exist (Mac or Windows) to browse folders with wildcards?

Tags: mac, synology, finder

I use a synology NAS, and have snapshots enabled. This creates a bunch of timestamped copies of folders in a #snapshots directory for each share. For instance, if I have the folder `homes/alex/my/folder/structure/` (where "homes" is a default share in DSM), I also have the folders `homes/#snapshots/<timestamp1, timestamp2, timestamp3, etc>/alex/my/folder/structure/` containing snapshots of the `structure` folder at all the timestamps it existed for. This whole structure is available to browse on a client machine via SMB, assuming you've enabled that and have a credentialed user and so on.

If I want to find all the snapshots of `structure` on MacOS, I can use the terminal command `ls /Volumes/homes/#snapshot/*/alex/my/folder/structure/'.

This is a little cumbersome both because it requires a lot of typing but also because it lists the entire contents of the `structure` folder at every snapshot, in addition to which snapshots there are.

In a perfect world, finder would just have a dropdown menu on the  folder path entry where I could see all the other folders at this level containing this same path I'm on, and could quickly switch between them. They do something similar with much more visual cruft in the Time Machine interface, but that's not generally applicable.

Is there any GUI a-la Path Finder/Forklift/etc that has this kind of function?

Comment: You can list just the snapshots (not their contents) with `ls -d /Volumes/homes/#snapshot/*/alex/my/folder/structure/` (the `-d` means list directories themselves, not their contents).

Comment: @alexwhittmore your current style question takes this good question into offtopic due that service and software recommendations not supported by serverfault.com. update the question to be more specific and then i take a review one again ;)